# Как достать ID из упоминания? vk_api

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Не пойму, как достать ID из упоминания. Взялся за команду `!kick`. Работает она таким способом:

`!kick ID пользователя`, но я хочу сделать так, чтобы данная команда работала вот так: `!kick @user <<< !kick [id0|user]`. `'@'` - Упомянуть пользователя в беседе.

Говорили использовать регулярные выражения, но не понимаю, как. Помогите пожалуйста решить, данный вопрос. Для меня, так сказать, это важно.

Код:

```
if request[0:5] == "!кик " and user_id in admin:

     vk.messages.removeChatUser(chat_id=chat_id, user_id=request[5:])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете воспользоваться регулярным выражением для того, чтобы извлечь `id` из сообщения.

Вот пример того, как это можно реализовать:

```py
import re


string = '!kick [id123456|user]'
user_id = re.findall(r'!kick \[id(\d*)\|.*]', string)[0]

print(user_id)
```

*stdout:*

```html
123456
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно ещё вот так:

```
if request[0:5] == "!кик ":

        import re

        kickId0 = event.object.get('text')[5:]
        kickId1 = kickId0.split('|')[0]
        kick_id = re.findall(r'id(.*)', KickId1)[0]     
        vk.messages.removeChatUser(user_id=kick_id,chat_id=event.chat_id)
```

Comment: Кстати, проверки на команду удобно делать с помощью `startswith`, например, так: `if request.startswith('!kick ')`.

Comment: @nomnoms12, А, что это `startswith`?

Comment: В переводе "начинается с". Проверка на то, начинается ли строка с указанной подстроки. Если да, то вернёт `True`, иначе - `False`.

Comment: @nomnoms12, Почитав в Google и прочитав ваш комментарий, я понял. Но, для чего она в этом коде?

Comment: Для красоты :) Я просто советую заменить `request[0:5]` на `startswith`. Как минимум, `startswith` не создаёт новый объект в памяти. Для работоспособности кода делать этого необязательно, это просто совет.

Comment: @nomnoms12, Окей, понял. Спасибо!